# Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**I installed react-native-location-enabler when i run my app it throw the error..**

> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
>   import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
>                                           ^
>     symbol:   class ApiException
>     location: package com.google.android.gms.common.api
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>   import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
>                                           ^
>     symbol:   class ResolvableApiException
>     location: package com.google.android.gms.common.api
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:63: error: cannot access ReflectedParcelable
>           LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
>                                                            ^
>     class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ReflectedParcelable not found
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:64: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
>           locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
>                          ^
>     class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
>               task.getResult(ApiException.class);
>                              ^
>     symbol:   class ApiException
>     location: class RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
>           } catch (ApiException exception) {
>                    ^
>     symbol:   class ApiException
>     location: class RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:104: error: cannot access CommonStatusCodes
>                   case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
>                                                   ^
>     class file for com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes not found
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
>                           ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
>                           ^
>     symbol:   class ResolvableApiException
>     location: class RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule
>   D:\carrental\node_modules\react-native-android-location-enabler\android\src\main\java\com\heanoria\library\reactnative\locationenabler\RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
>                           ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
>                                                                ^
>     symbol:   class ResolvableApiException
>     location: class RNAndroidLocationEnablerModule

**i tried 
 cd android && gradlew clean 
and it doesn't work.
"react-native": "^0.58.5"
"react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.1.0"
what i should to do to solve it.**

Comment: have you tried with installing jetifier and jetify

Comment: did you run `react-native` link?

Comment: yes i already tried react-native link

Comment: Finally i cleared the issue by deleting caches in .gradle folder

Comment: Can you provide detail as to how you did that?
How to clear cache in that folder?